# Why Are the Golden Tools/Armor So Weak? (Minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

What’s the use of gold? Seriously, come on. Gold is rarer than iron, yet the armor is almost as weak as the leather armor, which you can get from cows. The durability is terrible, and my tools break instantly. Iron is more common than gold, yet it has 15 armor bars (3rd most in the game), and the gold? Only 11. And the durability is so low! The iron tools have a durability of 251 hits! However, the golden tools only 33. Please, tell me, why did Notch make the golden tools/armor so weak?

Comment: Have *you* ever tried to dig a hole with a golden shovel?

Comment: This was a year ago, and I honestly have no idea what I was even talking about. But, yes golden shovels are pretty good, but I’ll admit, they do run out really quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Golden armor and tools are the easiest to enchant out of all the other armor and tools types. So gold has its perks, but I don’t understand why it’s so weak. Maybe Notch was trying to be realistic? In real life, gold armor would be much to heavy and soft to actually be used as armor.

Comment: I am aware of that